# my opencart website has 5k links and google indexes only 1200 links kindly help me

Tags: indexing, seo, opencart, google-search-console

i am running ecommerce website on opencart 
in google webmasters it shows [see index image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT21d.jpg)

kindly help me to solve this issue

Comment: Please update your question with - 2-3 urls not indexed.

Comment: This questions seems to have very little to do with programming. More google support forum...

Comment: i have posted in google forum too my brother

Answer (score 0):

Your question should be: Google is not indexing my site fast enough. Here are the reasons why?

1. Site PageRank
2. Server performance
3. Content relevance
4. External link quality

Get more links to each page and increase your server's performance levels, by increasing Memory and CPU count.

Comment: i had posted a thread in google forum with pics showing the issue     https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_source=wnc_582900&utm_medium=gamma&utm_campaign=wnc_582900&utm_content=msg_627200&hl=en#!topic/webmasters/gaQwc2SSk6Q;context-place=forum/webmasters